# How can I add a new user to my system's domain using .Net DirectoryServices?

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I want to write a Console application which will just add a new User to my own machine's Domain using .Net DirectoryServices API and LDAP.

Do I need admin account Password for the DomainController to do this ?

Do I need to run that Console Application on a machine on that domain only or can be run on other domains too ?

Can somebody provide me an example ?

**UPDATE:** Fetching the count of users code

```
DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection);
search.Filter = "(&objectClass=User)objectCategory=Person)userPrincipalName=*health2.com))";
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
SearchResultCollection allUsers = search.FindAll();
for (int usersCount = 0; usersCount < allUsers.Count; usersCount++)
{
    SearchResult result = allUsers[usersCount];
    if (result.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Count > 0)
    {
       string cn = result.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString();
       Console.WriteLine(cn);
       Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(@"Users Count - {0}", allUsers.Count.ToString()));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // do something here....     
}
```

The article I provided a link to also shows how easily you can create a new user and add it to AD:

```
// create a user principal object
UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ctx, "User1Acct", "pass@1w0rd01", true);

// assign some properties to the user principal
user.GivenName = "User";
user.Surname = "One";
user.UserPrincipalName = "user.one@health2.com";

// force the user to change password at next logon
user.ExpirePasswordNow();

// save the user to the directory
user.Save();
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: What is a Group here ? Is it the Domain name ? You provided me an example of enumerating Users, please please give me an example of Adding new user to domain name. The docs are very long, I will read them when I get some idle time. Thanks, if you can help.

Comment: I used your example to create a new user, it ran without any errors, but when I used the above code (in my update) to enumerate the users, it didn't show me the newly added user or even an increment in the count of users. It still shows only 1 user. Please see the above code I used to fetch the count of users.

Comment: @Puneet Dudeja: did you set a `userPrincipalName` for your new user that matches the search criteria of your filter? (`userPrincipalName=*health2.com)`) ?? Also: **where** in the LDAP tree are you searching?? Could it be your new user was created in an OU that is *not* part of your search??

Comment: `Health2.com` is the domain on which I am. I am unaware of all these terms, UserPrincipal, Principal etc. but just making a rough guess, I got this code from somewhere, to show all users in a particular domain (here my own domain).

Comment: Could you please come move this discussion to chat, if you have some time ?

Comment: @puneet dudeja: come over to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3212/add-new-user-to-active-directory